# Will Azure SQL database automatic upgrade to new service tiers?

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database

Currently I am using free 20 MB Azure SQL database web edition. Microsoft is going to retire the Azure Web and Business edition after 12 September 2015. Microsoft had announced new service tiers.

If I do not upgrade it to new service tiers, will it upgrade automatically? Which service tiers will it get upgraded to?

If it will not upgrade automatically, will my database get deleted or remains as usual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes if you don't upgrade, you will be automatically upgraded post Web and Business retirement. The destination service tier will be defined based on the billable size of the DBs. You can get details of the pricing tier here: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/04/24/azure-sql-database-introduces-new-service-tiers/

For free DBs specifically, we are working on a replacement for this SKU which will be available for the retirement date. Free DB will be mapped in the new Free DB SKU.

Thanks 
Silvia

Comment: Do I have to pay for the 20MB free SQL database after automatic upgrade?

Comment: @Chong: For free DBs specifically, we are working on a replacement for this SKU which will be available for the retirement date. Free DB will be mapped in the new Free DB SKU.

Answer (score 1):

I called Azure Sales number and the sales person told me that the free 20MB database will remain free of charge after the retirement of Web and Business pricing tier.

Besides that, I also create support ticket regarding this matter. The support engineer told me that the free 20 MB database will be automatically upgraded to a new free 20 MB database with Basic tier that carries characteristics of Basic except the database size. Attached is the picture of email sent by Azure Support Engineer:

[image: Email sent by Azure Support Engineer]